# Tkinter's .set method works in one spot, but not in another.

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, tkinter, ttk

Early on, I have this bit of code:

```
self.varCards = tk.StringVar()
self.varCards.set(3)
self.cmbCards = ttk.Combobox(self, state = 'readonly', width = 2, textvariable = self.varCards, values = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

This works fine, and sets the default value of the combobox to 3. But when I do essentially the same thing here, later on in another class:

```
self.varDrawing = tk.StringVar()
self.varDrawing.set(1)
self.opmDrawing = ttk.Combobox(self, state = 'readonly', width = 2, textvariable = self.varDrawing, values = initialize.listPlayers).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

It doesn't work. Everything about the combobox works fine, except for the set. It doesn't give me an error or anything, it just doesn't show the default value as 1. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `initialize.listPlayers`?

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `self.listPlayers = [1, 2, 3]` It's in another class, and changes. I replaced it with a list of options instead of a variable, and the same thing happened. It's a problem with the .set()

Comment: is your second code example producing the error in standalone run? I tried to verify what you describe but cannot reproduce the error. Please give us actual error producing code.